# Getting spinner value without using events

Tags: android, spinner

I'm trying to get the value from a spinner (android) without using events, like getting the value from a textbox.
Thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy just call up selected item on the Spinner

```
String Text = mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

You have getSelectedXXX methods from the AdapterView class from which the Spinner derives:

[getSelectedItem()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItem%28%29)

[getSelectedItemPosition()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItemPosition%28%29)

[getSelectedItemId()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItemId%28%29)